# Instantiating Java class with Class and/or ClassLoader

Tags: java, swing, class, jar, classloader

I'm trying to instantiate a class based on the file returned to me by a `JFileChooser`. So up to this point I have the `JFileChooser` working, and I can successfully grab the .class file I'm looking for. However, I'm having trouble actually taking that `.class` file and creating an object with it.

Here's the method that I'm writing...

```
public static Agent loadAgentFromFile(File file){
        Agent agent = null;
        String fileName = file.getName();
        String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String parentDirectory = file.getParentFile().getName();

        String agentClassName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));

        Object object = null;
        //System.out.println(filePath.contains(parentDirectory));
        //System.out.println(filePath.substring(0, filePath.indexOf(parentDirectory)));

        try {
            File f = new File(filePath.substring(0, filePath.indexOf(parentDirectory)));
            URL[] cp = {f.toURI().toURL()};
            URLClassLoader urlcl = new URLClassLoader(cp);

            Class agentDefinition = null;
            if (parentDirectory.equals("Agents"))
            {
                System.out.println(PACKAGE + agentClassName);
                agentDefinition = urlcl.loadClass(PACKAGE + agentClassName);
                //agentDefinition = Class.forName(PACKAGE + agentClassName);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(PACKAGE + parentDirectory + "." + agentClassName);
                agentDefinition = urlcl.loadClass(parentDirectory + "." + agentClassName);
            }
            object = agentDefinition.newInstance();

            agent = (Agent)object;
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(THIS,
                "The chosen class must not be an interface or be abstract, " +
                "and it must not have any arguments in its constructor.");
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(THIS,
                "The chosen class's constructor must be public.");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(THIS,
                "The chosen class cannot be found.  Make sure the .java file is compiled.");
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(THIS,
                "The chosen class does not extend from the Agent class.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //prints the stack to see what exception occurred that we didn't catch

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(THIS,
                "The chosen class does not conform to the \"Agent\" class.");
        }

        return agent;
    }
```

When this method gets called, however, I actually get a `NoClassDefFoundError`, which is caught by my catch-all Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestAgents/TestDFSAgent (wrong name: WumpusEnvironment/Model/Agent/TestAgents/TestDFSAgent)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at WumpusEnvironment.Model.Agent.AgentLoader.loadAgentFromFile(AgentLoader.java:41)
    at WumpusEnvironment.View.MainWindow.ApplicationWindow.actionPerformed(ApplicationWindow.java:270)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've look at previous answers of the same sort, and I originally had my `.class` files outside the entire package structure, so I moved them. My class files are inside the same folder as the source files now, but I still get this error. It may be pertinent to note that I'm trying to run this inside Eclipse, though in the future this entire project will be exported to a `.jar` file which will instantiate classes that won't be inside the package structure (since that's all inside the `.jar` at this point).

Could someone point me in the right direction here? I'd also appreciate pointers on how to make your suggestions continue to work when I export to a `.jar` file. I realize that the way Eclipse sets up some of the .class files relative to the `.java` files can sometimes mess these things up.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/718296/1324631.

Comment: You got the error because the name you said the class has is not the name that the class file actually contains -- the package name is different.

Comment: (I suspect that you need to get in bed with a true custom class loader, including the security/authorization gorp around it.  You need to be using `defineClass`.)

Comment: @AJMansfield I want to do that because I'm actually writing a small environment in which the main files that actually do things are written by other people. The environment just provides all the things an Agent needs to traverse the map, but Agents are written by others and uploaded into the environment to see how they run.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone point me in the right direction here?

I think that the right direction is don't do it this way.  I recommend that you:

1. Put the plugin agent classes into JAR files (with the correct paths inside the JAR).
2. Create individual classloaders for each JAR file or one for all of them ... depending on whether agent classes need to be isolated from each other.

The exceptions you are running into happen because the classes package name does not match the path to the ".class" file from the classloader's root directory.  In the worst case, you cannot make it match ... without moving the ".class" file, or writing a custom classloader that does something tricky.  And even then, you have the (potential) problem of dealing with wanted or unwanted dependencies on other ".class" files.

Putting the plugins into JARs avoids these problems.

Comment: Sure, I could totally do this, but the issue is that I don't know what the Agent classes will actually be. Refer to my comment on the main post about this--I could potentially have an infinite number of different Agent files, all of which need to be able to by uploaded into my environment dynamically. I won't be the one actually using any of these Agent files, others will use them in the environment...I'm just writing a few to test that stuff works the way it's supposed to.

Comment: It might be better to rephrase my question from scratch if that would help you help me: how do I use Class.forName() or class loaders to dynamically instantiate objects that extend Agent, based on .class files selected from a file chooser?

Comment: @BhargavB - The answer to that is that you would need to solve a bunch of messy (and in some cases unsolvable) problems.  IMO it is better not to try.  Do it using JAR files instead.  Redesign your UI.  Choosing ".class" files from the filesystem in a FileChooser is a BAD IDEA.