# Java load class from Jar and handover complex data type

Tags: java, reflection, jar, classloader

I would like to load a class from another JAR (imported as file during runtime) and handover an Object (this) to the Constructor of the class which should be loaded.

I tried doing that with the following code:

```
URLClassLoader cl2 = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] { new URL("jar:file:" + jarPath +"!/") });
Class c2 = cl2.loadClass("main.Class2BeLoaded");
Object loadedClass = c2.getConstructor(Object4Constructor.class).newInstance(this));
```

It seems so, that the Object which I handover to the constructor (this) can't be used from the code which runs in the JAR.

What is wrong? If I run this code in the same JAR everything works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load Classes at runtime from a folder or JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar)

Comment: That question doesn't answer my question. I edited my post - now it should be clearly what I mean

Comment: Don't use `newInstance(this)`.  Instead, you need something like this: `(Test)Class.forName("Test").getConstructor(String.class).newInstance("Hello World");`  Here the getConstructor asks what the constructor looks like (it wants a string) and then you call it with a string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712371/

Comment: With `URLClassLoader` you should always provide a parent loader: `URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {...}, getClass().getClassLoader());`. On trying to instantiate `main.Class2BeLoaded` Java will also attempt to load all dependent classes, `Object4Constructor` in your case. As the classloader of `main.Class2BeLoaded` however has no parent, it can't find the class definition for `Object4Constructor` and therefore fails initializing the dynamically loaded object. On passing `getClass().getClassLoader()` you tell `URLClassLoader` to ask its parent for class definitions it doesn't know.