# Can I instantiate the Class object using its name

Tags: java

I have a class suppose Learning.java

Can I instantiate that class using its name "Learning.java" ? I went through reflection in JAVA, But I think that instantiates only the .class objects.

I wanted to call a method `calculate()` through an interface `ILearning.java`

`Learning.java` has constructor which takes arguments `(int a,int b,int c,int d)`

and the calculate method takes those argument and returns double.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Instantiate a class using the class object? What about Constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712371/can-i-instantiate-a-class-using-the-class-object-what-about-constructors)

Comment: What is your code, what is the input, what is the *specific* output?

Comment: This SO question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092659/what-is-the-difference-between-class-forname-and-class-forname-newinstanc

Comment: `Learning.java` is not a class. It is a file with source code. In order to instantiate an object, you need to compile the code(.class file) and load it in JVM via classloader.

Comment: You can check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886266/is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-class-by-name-in-java

Comment: Stop explaining code, **show code**. What classes are involved, where do you have a `String` containing a class name, and why do you have it, where does it come from, why do you not just use a proper instance in the first place, etc!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using the package name along with the class as below

```
 Class<?> myClass= Class.forName("com.Learning");
```

I got the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate using "Learning.java" file using reflection. However, having Learning.class file in the classpath and using reflection API such as Class.forName() you can instantiate.